# Creating a container for cURL'd content

Tags: php, css, curl

I'm using curl to get a page.  The problem is, I'm trying to have my own "header" div an the curl content at the bottom.  The CSS from the cURL is messing up my formatting though.  How do I contain the cURL'd content without putting in an iframe?

```
public function curl ($url, $options)
{
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($handle, $options);
    ob_start();
    $buffer = curl_exec($handle);
    ob_end_clean();
    curl_close($handle);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$content = curl($url, $options = array());

preg_match('/<body>(.*?)</body>/is', $content, $matches);

if(!empty($matches)) {

 $body = $matches[0];

 //header with your css
 echo $header;

 //parsed content 
 echo $body;

 //footer
 echo $footer;
}
```

note: code not tested.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 That should work as long as the style elements are not in the body... if it still an issue you could preg_replace them away.

Answer (score 0):

You can try outputting only its body to avoid loading any other css files.